# Neo4j How to check the relationships for an specific node

Tags: neo4j

I'm reading about relationships and how I can obtain the relations of each individual node.

Just now, I have a node `A` with relation [:MATCH] with a node `B`, also I have the node`C` and the node `D`.

I could have more node relations with [:MATCH] in other nodes.

How I can obtain only relations of an specific node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cypher you can bind variables to relationships in a pattern. For example:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:WORKS_FOR]->(c:Company)
WHERE p.name = "Bob"
RETURN r;
```

Will bind any `:WORKS_FOR` relationships to the variable `r` for the Person node with name property "Bob".

Answer (score 0):

To see an specific relation you can use:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:WORKS_FOR]->(c:Company)
WHERE p.name = "Bob"
RETURN r;
```

But, If you need see a Bidirectional relation, you can use:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:WORKS_FOR]-(c:Person)
WHERE p.email= "john@gmail.com"
RETURN r;
```

When you can use it?, For example, if you have a friend you can say:
*John is Friend of Mary*, and *Mary is John's Friend*.
Add two relationships is a bad pattern in Neo4J, but you can use `-` wihout the symbol `>` to not specify direction of the relationship.